# What role does JS play in this Foundation html template?

Tags: zurb-foundation

So I made the mistake of using this html template for a project I'm working on.  http://foundation.zurb.com/templates/store.html#

For whatever reason, the dropdown menus in the nav bar work are working, and whenever I hover over a link in the dropdown I see the correct URL displayed in the status bar at the bottom of the browser, but when I click the link, the page doesn't load.  I'm at a loss as to why.

To complicate matters, the CSS in Foundation is wayyy too intensive for what I'm trying to do, there seems to be thousands of lines to sift through and why is there any javascript at all?

So my question is what is the function of foundation.js in this template and does it have anything to do with why the links in the nav bar aren't working?

Comment: I looked at the URL you provided and it seems that all the links in the navigation are using href="#" which will only take you to the top of the page when clicked. As for the javascript, at a glance, there does not seem to be a need for it, but I'd have to look into it further.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put more information in my post.  I have changed the links in my local project, when I hover over them, I see the url in the status bar, yet clicking them does not load the page.

Comment: Even if i don't edit the links and leave them at href="#", I see 127.0.0.1:8000/# in that status bar when I hover over the link.  Clicking on it does nothing though and I believe at the very least, clicking on a # link should return the page to the top scroll position, which it is not doing on my local machine.

Comment: Thanks for the further info. It sounds like the click events for your links are being stopped to perform some other operation. If you comment out the script includes, you should then see the links going somewhere.

Comment: Okay I disabled javascript and the links now work, hopefully I can now pinpoint the exact .js file that is causing this, thanks.

Comment: The culprit was modernizr.js